Bookable Appointment Schedule Via flutter - android studio
I'm building an appointment app in flutter for iOS and android. I'm using Google Calendar's API for that. I'm trying to use the new feature of calendar,bookable appointment schedule in order to do that, but I can't manage to get this event via code.
// Get all available hours from the appointment schedule event of the selected date
  Future<List<String>> getAllAvailableHours(DateTime selectedDate) async {
    print('Fetching available hours for date: $selectedDate');
    try {
      // Authenticate client
      final client = await _getClient();

      // we have a right client creds


      // Initialize Calendar API
      final calendarApi = calendar.CalendarApi(client);

      print('calendarApi : $calendarApi');

      // Define start and end time for the selected day
      DateTime startTime = DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day, 0, 0, 0);
      DateTime endTime = DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day, 23, 59, 59);

      print('Start Time Is: $startTime');
      print('endTime Is: $endTime');

      // Fetch events from Google Calendar
      final events = await calendarApi.events.list(_calendarId, timeMin: startTime.toUtc(), timeMax: endTime.toUtc());



      //return availableHours;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching available hours: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }

Google calendar API is already integrated even after multiple checkings, and I can get normal events, just not the new feature event the bookable appointment schedule.
